# Why changing default library's default save location does not affect softwares/games in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

What I meant by the question is: I've set only one folder (namely, `E:\My Documents`) as my "Documents" library. This is also default save location for Documents. `C:\` is my system drive. `C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents` is the default documents folder that is provided by Windows 7. I've found that games like FIFA 09 and NFS Shift is saving their settings and user data in `C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents\[GameName]` folder. I wanted it to be saved in `E:\My Documents\[GameName]` folder.

This didn't happen in Windows XP. For example, I set `E:\My Documents` as my documents folder using TweakUI and all the games saved their data in `E:\My Documents\[GameName]` folder. Seems this isn't happening in Windows 7.

Is there any other way to redirect default document folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libraries are just a logical view on several folders. Defining a Documents library (whether it contains only 1 directory or more) does not change the default location for the Documents folder. They're 2 different entities for Windows 7.

If you want to move the Documents folder to another drive, follow the instructions on this site: [**How to Change My Documents Folder Default Location Path in Windows 7, Vista and XP**](http://www.gokhiel.com/2009/05/how-to-change-my-documents-folder.html)

> **Windows 7**
>
> 1. Create a new folder that you want to assign as My Documents folder, if
>      you have another drive or partition
>      ex: drive D: I recommended that you
>      create My Document Folder to that
>      drive.
> 2. browse to "C:\Users\" using Windows Explorer (Press WINDOWS
>      KEY + E to access this). Then, right
>      click on My Documents and select
>      Properties: Then Click Location Tab
> 3. Then click Move then browse to new location for your My Documents folder.
>      Once you find new folder for your
>      document click Select Folder
> 4. then click Apply, there will be pop up message to confirm the changed,
>      click Yes to move your documents to
>      the new location, or click No to leave
>      your documents in the original
>      location.